# What is the easiest method of working with a mailbox on an exchange server using .NET from a remote client?

Tags: .net, exchange-server, webdav

So I have to make a windows service that scans incoming mails in a mailbox on an exchange server for specific words and then deletes the mail. The mailbox I will be scanning currently holds more than 70000 mails. I've tried using the [exchange WebDAV protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa143161(EXCHG.65).aspx), but it usually times out before responding. Are there any alternatives to WebDAV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned  out that the WebDAV protocol contains several meths for bulk operations as well as list response limitation constructs. The two really useful contructs I found were the [Range Header](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa123634(EXCHG.65).aspx) and the [BDELETE Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa142716(EXCHG.65).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Exchange 2007 SP1 or later, you should be able to use [Exchange Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb408417.aspx). Don't be surprised if it isn't particularly fast - I couldn't get it to go faster than around 100 email retrievals per minute. The API was usable fairly quickly, though.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to access the mailbox via imap or pop3.

Also microsoft provide someway to hook the SMTP server. [check](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms528309(EXCHG.10).aspx) this link for details.

But I think the solution for you would be a place a gateway server before your exchange infrastructure and use the hook posibilities of postfix or other SMTP.